# I have created a time series forecast model in SPSS using expert modeler. I have 300 products and wish to apply the model on all of these

Tags: time-series, spss-modeler

Is there some method that the model takes the data for all 300 products and gives analysis? Should some coding be done? I am absolutely new to coding.

Comment: I'd recommend asking this question over at [datascience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) since it's not really in the scope of a coding question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the guidance!!!